# почему у меня не работает функция employee()

Tags: python, python-3.x

код

```
pizza = 4.99
coffee = 1.49
hamburger = 3.49
coca_colla = 1.99
password = 123321

def employee():
    pass1 = input("Введите пароль: ")
    if pass1 == password:
        return "Добро пожаловать! \n Пицца =" + pizza + "; \n  Кофе =" + coffee + "; \n 
Гамбургер = " + hamburger + "; \n Кока-кола = " + coca_colla
    else:
        return "Пароль введен неверно! "
#def buyer():
def menu():
    account_1 = str(input("Вы сотрудник или покупатель ? \n Если вы сотрудник то нажмите 
y(aнгл); Если вы покупатель, то нажмите n(aнгл): " ))
    if account_1 == "y":
        print(employee())
    elif account_1 == "n":
        buyer()
    else:
        print("Ввели что-то не правельно, попробуйте ещё раз! ")
menu()
```

Comment: первое, что видно ве ваши пиццы и гамбургеры надо переводить в строки, сейчас они у вас числа. Их нельзя объединять со строками плюсом. А вообще, пишите ошибку и в какой строке она произошла

Comment: Потому что pass1 - строка, а password - число.

Answer (score 1):

Исправил ваш код.

```
pizza = 4.99
coffee = 1.49
hamburger = 3.49
coca_colla = 1.99
password = 123321

def employee():
    pass1 = int(input('Введите пароль: '))
    if pass1 == password:
        return f'Добро пожаловать! \n Пицца {pizza} \n Кофе {coffee} \n Бургер {hamburger} \n Кола {coca_colla}'
    return 'Пароль введен неверно!'
    #def buyer():
def menu():
    account_1 = input('Вы сотрудник или покупатель ? у-покупать n-сотрудник')
    if account_1 == 'y':
        print(employee())
    #elif account_1 == 'n':
        #buyer()
    else:
        print('Ввели что-то не правильно, попробуйте ещё раз!')

menu()
```

Comment: Зачем в конструкции `f"{pizza}"` str ?

Comment: @splash58 исправлено.

Comment: Если уж речь про `PEP8`, то не надо ли тогда константы называть прописными буквами? ))

Comment: @CrazyElf еще на всидку  - проьельные строки вокруг функций и разбить первый ретурн на две строки

Comment: @splash58 Мне от вас душно, но поддерживаю. Однако проблему у человека я решил.

Comment: @DaYa Так вы сами зачем-то `PEP8` упомянули, вас никто за язык не тянул ))

Comment: @CrazyElf Исправлено.